# Sencha Touch Watermark

Tags: sencha-touch, watermark

Is there a method in Sencha Touch to set input watermark like jQuery watermark plugin?

I'm using general HTML input text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called the `placeHolder` property of a textfield